# Updating field in icefaces using thread

Tags: java

Good morning guys

I have a textField on my icefaces page which display number of messages in one table in a database.

Since that data changes from other users using the application so I want to update that field after some interval ,lets say every 5 minutes.

Does any one have idea what could be the best way to solve this issue ?

Is it ok to use a thread in the background which sleeps for that interval and change the bean value which is displayed on the page (not sure if it works )?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the value in an application variable, where all the sessions can update and read from it? You can also synchronize it with the database regularly